# Installing on a separate hard drive partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have two hard drives on my computer, one SSD with windows (C:) and another for storing documents (F:). I created a free space on F: to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7.

Can you confirm my partition settings are correct ?

[image]

Also what should I select for boot loader installation?

Comment: Yes. Your partition settings are correct and the device for boot loader installation is /dev/sda.

Comment: Thank you, but when I clicked on "Instal Now" I had an error, apparently my installation media is corrupted.

Comment: For issues with the integrity of the installation medium see [Installation/CDIntegrityCheck](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck) and/or [HowToMD5SUM](//help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM). If this doesn't solve your problem, look for related question or [open your own](/questions/ask).

Comment: The CD integrity check went fine. I restarted my computer and clicked immediately on Install. The first I messed around with the system a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The partitions look alright.

I would put the boot loader on `sda`, because it's faster and that's where the operating systems reside anyway.

Comment: the `/dev/sda` is my SSD where the Windows installation is. Isn't it where the bootloader should be?

Comment: But the partition table on `sda` is reported empty. Weird…